# Save python output into Django Models

Tags: python, django

I have this code in my views.py:

```
def home_output(request):
    commandRun = 'python script.py'
    data = os.system(commandRun)
    print(data)
    return render(request, 'home-view.html', {'data': data})
```

So when I open the page in Django, there is button to run the above code. When I run the server, and click the button, I get errors on the screen, but I can see the output in my terminal, which means, button worked and ran the script.

All I want is to capture that output, and show it on the web page.

I'm new to Django, so I don't know how to approach this problem. Do I have to modify my script to go to django.models and save some data?
Or should I do something in Django to capture the data?

I need some guidance like how to go forward..

Comment: When you click on button you need to create ajax call for particular URL and in that url you need to run that command and get output. you can use `subprocess.call` as well. and return your output as json in ajax request.

Comment: What errors you see? Please update your question with this error